# h5py package clashes with numpy

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have installed h5py using `conda install h5py`.
However when importing the package by `import h5py` , I come along the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c9f0b8c65221> in <module>()
----> 1 import h5py

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py in <module>()
     34 _errors.silence_errors()
     35 
---> 36 from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
     37 _register_converters()
     38 

h5py\h5t.pxd in init h5py._conv()

h5py\numpy.pxd in init h5py.h5t()

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I want to install h5py in order to load a pretrained model in Keras. 
I have tried reinstalling h5py and numpy multiple times, still the same outcome.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried installing h5py with pip from PyPI instead?

Comment: I tried now, but I get the following: `Collecting h5py
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/1e/115c4403544a91001d9c618748b2e8786db45544e36b8a6cf3c525e9b57f/h5py-2.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from h5py) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from h5py) (1.12.0)
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow-1.13.1.dist-info\\METADATA'`

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a new environment in conda and try it there again.

Comment: I wiped everything python-related and installed all over again, now it works. For anyone wondering about versions and similar, I followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59duINoc8GM